# How to draw a rectangle on imageview instead of a view in ipad

Tags: iphone, cgcontext

Hi in my project i have a imageview i would like to draw a rectangle or circle on image view with our finger moments.now i did already by using CGContext class methods but that rectangle and circles are created on one UIView object with the help of draw rect method. That created view is adding on imageview like a circle or rectangle but i wish to draw that directly on imageview is itpossible to do that please help me in this issue.

Comment: UIImageView is a subclass of UIView. Have you tried overriding the UIImageView's drawRect?

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView is a subclass of UIView, but you cannot override `drawRect:` for UIImageView.

Try to add a sublayer and draw in that sublayer use delegation and `drawLayer:inContext:` method

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/ProvidingCALayerContent.html